# Does the drive Windows 7 calls "BD-ROM" really support Blu-Ray?

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray

I have a drive in my machine that Windows 7 lists as a BD-ROM drive. In fact, it lists it twice, along with another DVD-RW drive, when in fact I only have one physical optical drive on my machine.

Given that there's no Blu-Ray logo on the drive itself, I'm presuming that it doesn't actually support Blu-Ray. How can I be sure? And how do I convince Windows 7 it's not a Blu-Ray drive?

Comment: It is probably a virtual drive mounted as a Blu-Ray drive to your system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the validity of the drive by looking in the device manager. Sometimes if you run applications such as Alcohol 120%, daemon tools, power ISO, and so on they make virtual drives, which might appear as Blu-Ray drives.

Comment: Thanks for that prompt: device manager showed that one of the drives is definitely a virtual drive, so I'm guessing the other is too.

Answer (score 1):

The "BD-ROM" drive is most likely a utility from a company called "Syloft" which allows you to mount an ISO image of a CD or DVD as if it were an actual physical disk.

Right-clicking on the BD-ROM icon should bring up a context menu with "Virtual Clone Drive" as one of the options.

From this you can mount an ISO image on your hard drive and it will appear just as if it had been burned to disk and inserted in your optical drive.